# Pinescript ATR of Different Timeframe

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to calculate ATR on a different timeframe than the current chart?  For example, I am looking at a 15 minute chart, and I want to see the ATR of the 1 hour chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
atr14 = atr(14)
atr1hour = security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", atr14)
```